# SQLite syntax error with Encrypted-Core-Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, encrypted-core-data-sql

I've been running into a syntax error for a very long time now and I am unsure as to what could be causing it. The debug log is as follows:

```
SQL DEBUG: SELECT ecdImages.checkSum, ecdImages.creationDate, ecdImages.filename, ecdImages.height, ecdImages.latitude, ecdImages.locationString, ecdImages.longitude, ecdImages.order, ecdImages.photoId, ecdImages.photoLogValues, ecdImages.requiresDeletion, ecdImages.requiresUpload, ecdImages.rotationAngle, ecdImages.scale, ecdImages.source, ecdImages.timestamp, ecdImages.title, ecdImages.transform, ecdImages.width, ecdImages.x, ecdImages.y, ecdImages.book__objectid, ecdImages.page__objectid FROM ecdImages WHERE ecdImages.__objectid=?;

could not prepare statement: near "order": syntax error
```

Order is of type Integer 16 and for your reference, I am currently using Encrypted-Core-Data as found on github. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would this syntax error be occurring because I'm using a keyword that is normally reserved for other things? I tried changing 'order' to 'level' and the error seems to have gone away. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: [SQLite Keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: Hi CL,
Thank you very much for your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by CL in the comments, I was using a reserved keyword. Refer to [SQLite Keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).